# Get table total

Tags: jquery, html

I have a html table as the following, I also have an option to add rows dynamically.

```
                            <tbody>
                            <tr style="display: none" id="invoiceRow">
                                <td><textarea></textarea></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="quantity" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="rate" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="amount" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="deleteInvoiceRow(this);" class="btn btn-small">
                                        <i class="icon-remove"></i>                     
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><textarea></textarea></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="quantity" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="rate" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td class="va_middle"><input type="text" name="amount" class="mini" /></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a onclick="deleteInvoiceRow(this);" class="btn btn-small">
                                        <i class="icon-remove"></i>                     
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2"><a onclick="addNewInvoiceRow();"><i class="icon-plus-sign right"></i></a></td>
                                <td class="va_middle" colspan="3">&nbsp; <strong>Total: &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong><input type="text" name="rate" class="total" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
```

I would like to get the total of each row and update it to the total field in the last tr.

How do I do it with jQuery? and update the value on change of the value.

Comment: You say you have an option to add rows dynamically. Could you please post the jQuery code related to that?

Answer (score 0):

the way I will do it is by adding couple listeners to the TABLE tag, and also I m assuming that the input with name "amount" will be equal to the product of "rate" by "quantity". the code could look like:

```
function calcTotalTable() {
    var total = 0;
    $('my_table input[name="amount"]').each(function(){
        // add some validation
        total += $j(this).val();
    });

    $('my_table input.total').val(total);
}

$('my_table').on('change', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    var $row = $(this).closest('tr'),
        // you may need to add some validation before the calculation
        total = $row.find('input[name="quantity"]').val() * $row.find('input[name="rate"]').val();
    $row.find('input[name="amount"]').val(total);
    calcTotalTable();
}).on('click', 'a.btn btn-small', function() { // theses will handle the delete btn
        $(this).closest('tr').remove();
        calcTotalTable();
    });
```

of course you will need to take care of validation and formatting, but code will do the basic process. I haven't test this code but will give you the general idea.
I hope helps, best!